# getting error ##[error]One of the deployment parameters has an empty key. when running pipeline to deploy AKS cluster

Tags: json, azure, devops

I'm trying to deploy one AKS cluster using json file in Azure Devops and whwn running the pipeline I get the error: ##[error]One of the deployment parameters has an empty key.
I checked the json file but I have no idea what the problem could be?
Any ideas  how to check ?
This is my json file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
    "parameters": {
        "clusterName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue":"aks101cluster",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the Managed Cluster resource."
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The location of the Managed Cluster resource."
            }
        },
        "dnsPrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Optional DNS prefix to use with hosted Kubernetes API server FQDN."
            }
        },
        "osDiskSizeGB": {
            "type": "int",
            "defaultValue": 0,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Disk size (in GB) to provision for each of the agent pool nodes. This value ranges from 0 to 1023. Specifying 0 will apply the default disk size for that agentVMSize."
            },
            "minValue": 0,
            "maxValue": 1023
        },
        "agentCount": {
            "type": "int",
            "defaultValue": 3,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The number of nodes for the cluster."
            },
            "minValue": 1,
            "maxValue": 50
        },
        "agentVMSize": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Standard_DS2_v2",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The size of the Virtual Machine."
            }
        },
        "linuxAdminUsername": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "sysadmin"
            "metadata": {
                "description": "User name for the Linux Virtual Machines."
            }
        },
        "sshRSAPublicKey": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Configure all linux machines with the SSH RSA public key string. Your key should include three parts, for example 'ssh-rsa AAAAB...snip...UcyupgH azureuser@linuxvm'"
            }
        },
        "servicePrincipalClientId": {
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Client ID (used by cloudprovider)"
            },
            "type": "securestring"
        },
        "servicePrincipalClientSecret": {
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The Service Principal Client Secret."
            },
            "type": "securestring"
        },
        "osType": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Linux",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Linux"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The type of operating system."
            }
        }        
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2020-03-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "name": "[parameters('clusterName')]",
            "properties": {
                "dnsPrefix": "[parameters('dnsPrefix')]",
                "agentPoolProfiles": [
                    {
                        "name": "agentpool",
                        "osDiskSizeGB": "[parameters('osDiskSizeGB')]",
                        "count": "[parameters('agentCount')]",
                        "vmSize": "[parameters('agentVMSize')]",
                        "osType": "[parameters('osType')]",
                        "storageProfile": "ManagedDisks"
                    }
                ],
                "linuxProfile": {
                    "adminUsername": "[parameters('linuxAdminUsername')]",
                    "ssh": {
                        "publicKeys": [
                            {
                                "keyData": "[parameters('sshRSAPublicKey')]"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "servicePrincipalProfile": {
                    "clientId": "[parameters('servicePrincipalClientId')]",
                    "Secret": "[parameters('servicePrincipalClientSecret')]"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "controlPlaneFQDN": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[reference(parameters('clusterName')).fqdn]"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma (,) after `"defaultValue": "sysadmin"`.

This is the right json:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
    "parameters": {
        "clusterName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue":"aks101cluster",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the Managed Cluster resource."
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The location of the Managed Cluster resource."
            }
        },
        "dnsPrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Optional DNS prefix to use with hosted Kubernetes API server FQDN."
            }
        },
        "osDiskSizeGB": {
            "type": "int",
            "defaultValue": 0,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Disk size (in GB) to provision for each of the agent pool nodes. This value ranges from 0 to 1023. Specifying 0 will apply the default disk size for that agentVMSize."
            },
            "minValue": 0,
            "maxValue": 1023
        },
        "agentCount": {
            "type": "int",
            "defaultValue": 3,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The number of nodes for the cluster."
            },
            "minValue": 1,
            "maxValue": 50
        },
        "agentVMSize": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Standard_DS2_v2",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The size of the Virtual Machine."
            }
        },
        "linuxAdminUsername": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "sysadmin",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "User name for the Linux Virtual Machines."
            }
        },
        "sshRSAPublicKey": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Configure all linux machines with the SSH RSA public key string. Your key should include three parts, for example 'ssh-rsa AAAAB...snip...UcyupgH azureuser@linuxvm'"
            }
        },
        "servicePrincipalClientId": {
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Client ID (used by cloudprovider)"
            },
            "type": "securestring"
        },
        "servicePrincipalClientSecret": {
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The Service Principal Client Secret."
            },
            "type": "securestring"
        },
        "osType": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Linux",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Linux"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The type of operating system."
            }
        }        
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2020-03-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "name": "[parameters('clusterName')]",
            "properties": {
                "dnsPrefix": "[parameters('dnsPrefix')]",
                "agentPoolProfiles": [
                    {
                        "name": "agentpool",
                        "osDiskSizeGB": "[parameters('osDiskSizeGB')]",
                        "count": "[parameters('agentCount')]",
                        "vmSize": "[parameters('agentVMSize')]",
                        "osType": "[parameters('osType')]",
                        "storageProfile": "ManagedDisks"
                    }
                ],
                "linuxProfile": {
                    "adminUsername": "[parameters('linuxAdminUsername')]",
                    "ssh": {
                        "publicKeys": [
                            {
                                "keyData": "[parameters('sshRSAPublicKey')]"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "servicePrincipalProfile": {
                    "clientId": "[parameters('servicePrincipalClientId')]",
                    "Secret": "[parameters('servicePrincipalClientSecret')]"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "controlPlaneFQDN": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[reference(parameters('clusterName')).fqdn]"
        }
    }
}
```